# File is not shown in OpenFileDialog

Tags: vb.net, file

I'm trying to do something like a text editor in VB 2012, so I have a MenuStrip with an "OpenFile" option. When it's clicked it fires an OpenFileDialog control and shows me just the files with the extension I want. The problem is that if I close the file with another option in the menu strip, when I want to open the same file I opened the first time using the same OpenFile option the OpenFileDialog is not showing me the file.

Do you know why is that?

Here is how I open the file:

```
Private Sub OpenFileToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles OpenFileToolStripMenuItem.Click
    'Open File
    If OpenFile.ShowDialog() = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
        If Not (OpenFile.FileName = "") And OpenFile.CheckFileExists Then
            NewFile = New StreamReader(OpenFile.FileName)
            If NewFile IsNot Nothing Then
                Me.TextBox_Main.Text = NewFile.ReadToEnd
                Me.TabPage1.Text = OpenFile.FileName.Substring(OpenFile.FileName.LastIndexOf("\") + 1)
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

And here is how I close the file:

```
Private Sub CloseFileToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CloseFileToolStripMenuItem.Click
    'Close Files
    If NewFile IsNot Nothing Then
        NewFile.Close()
        NewFile = Nothing
    End If
    Me.TextBox_Main.Text = ""
    Me.TabPage1.Text = "New Tab"
End Sub
```

Comment: Closing the filestream is not the same as saving the file.  There is no need to keep the stream open once the contents have been read.

Comment: So I should Open the file, read, and then close inmediatly, yeah it makes sense, I did it, but it still doesn't show the file when I fire the OpenFileDialog again

Comment: You dont show the OFD settings like the filters etc, so it is hard to say.  YOur stream reader also needs to be Disposed of not just closed  (visit MSDN and look up Using)

Comment: If you save the filename, you can set the OpenFileDialog.FileName the next time you want to open the OFD. Incidentally, instead of `OpenFile.FileName.Substring(OpenFile.FileName.LastIndexOf("\") + 1)` you can use `Path.GetFileName(OpenFile.FileName)`.